# Redirect browser to different host and port

Tags: windows, port, hosts, redirection, rewrite

Background, Running windows 7, FF3.5, and am an admin. I recieve emails from an internal company service that has links. The problem is the links don't work from my office. If the resource is http://sub1.sub2.domain.com/page.html, I need to go to h t t p://so.me.ip:8080/page.html. (spaces in http because i am only allowed one link...)

The gist is a need to map a domain to an ip AND port. I am open to ideas that are system wide, browser (some kind of plugin?) or even somehow modifying the email as it comes in to outlook. I am pretty technical so don't hold back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If it was just straight IP mapping, then using your hosts file would do the job fine, but changing the port as well is somewhat more complex. I'm not aware of any local software that would let you do this, what I'd do is to set up a proxy/firewall between you and the remote server (I've used squid in the past, which is also caching), and setting up rewrite rules on there to map one url/port to another.

If these are links that can be accessed from the internal network normally, then perhaps connecting in with a VPN would be the simplest solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [FoxyProxy](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/) plugin for FireFox in the past in these situations, and it's worked out pretty well. It lets you map a proxy for FF only, leaving the rest of your network settings in tact.

Let me know if that works out for you. Good luck!

Comment: Can't you already do that by going to Tools->Options->Advanced->Network->Settings ?
Thats not exactly what I want.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, and no. FireFox can ignore the system proxy settings if you choose, and FoxyProxy is an extension on that to let you easily change back and forth between proxies. I find the tools>options route rather cumbersome, and with FP I can just right-click on the status bar and change my proxy for FF without changing the system proxy. In addition, FoxyProxy lets you map out certain patterns, so you can create a "work" proxy, but have all so.me.ip be changed to so.me.ip:8080.

Comment: Any input on how to do that? I just installed FoxyProxy standard. I see I can add patterns, but no where to add a mapping...

Answer (score 2):

Both of the following two applications will do what you want:

Fiddler (Free) http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Charles Debugging Proxy (Shareware) http://www.xk72.com/charles.

You can map hosts/ip/url etc with either tool. I just went through the same issue a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting your email via the web or with a client?

If it is over the web, and because you are using Firefox, you can use the [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) AddOn.  You will have to code your own script to get what you're asking for, but here is one to get you started: [URL fixer](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/6564)